# Is there a built-in Ruby way to convert a query string directly into a JSON object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

If I had a string :

```
"TimeStamp=1320947201017&enumber=34646"
```

And wanted this to be JSON :

```
{ "TimeStamp" : "1320947201017", "enumber" : "34646" }
```

Is there a built-in way to accomplish this in Ruby?

Comment: edit your subject as *a query string directly..*

Comment: Cool, great idea. Just did thanks Arup

Comment: No.. you did it wrong :-) *query string to Json*... like this..

Comment: ok i think i got it.. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do as below :

```
require 'uri'
require 'json'

Hash[URI.decode_www_form("TimeStamp=1320947201017&enumber=34646")].to_json
# => "{\"TimeStamp\":\"1320947201017\",\"enumber\":\"34646\"}"
```

Documentation - [`decode_www_form`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form) and [`Generating JSON`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON)

Comment: Wow that's really interesting. I had never seen that before. Thanks!

Comment: I thought that the OP wanted it in JSON, not a Ruby hash. bjhaid's edit makes it do that, but bjhad should not have edited someone else's code. It is inappropriate to change someone else's answer substantially.

Comment: You added `to_json` but forgot to update the output from Hash to JSON.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thank youuuuuuuu... :-) I always forgot... everything :p

Comment: Yup.  #=> "{\"TimeStamp\":\"1320947201017\",\"enumber\":\"34646\"}"

Comment: @KirtiThorat I used in my editor `puts` which gave exactly the same as OP... But I removed `puts` here, and *forgot* to change the output..

Comment: `puts` will give that but `irb` would give this(escape ").

Comment: @KirtiThorat.. Yes,, I know. That was my mistake.. Like I always did. You know it better.. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Convert it to a hash, then convert the hash to json, both using rails' inbuilt methods.

```
require 'rack/utils'
#=> []
paramstring = "TimeStamp=1320947201017&enumber=34646"
#=> "TimeStamp=1320947201017&enumber=34646"
hash = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(paramstring)
#=> {"TimeStamp"=>"1320947201017", "enumber"=>"34646"}
hash.to_json    
#=> "{\"TimeStamp\":\"1320947201017\",\"enumber\":\"34646\"}"
```

Comment: Wow Max Williams, you're a legend! Thanks!